# Bonjour: how to configure macOS 10.14 to reach subdomains within machine.local domain?

Tags: macos, networking, dns, localhost, bonjour

Developing services on a macOS 10.14 machine, we would like to reach each different service with a subdomain (akin to what will happen in production).

Assume the machine's name is "bar", then we can access it with the `bar.local` url.
Yet, we cannot find a way to redirect some (or all) subdomains to the same machine. E.g:

- service1.bar.local
- service2.bar.local

Is it possible to achieve such behaviour only using tools from the vanilla macOS 10.14 distribution, and without hardcoding the machine name in a config file (i.e., not explicitly duplicating the machine name in `/etc/host`)?

Comment: I have been trying to figure this out myself. Is it possible to add Bonjour aliases?

Comment: @MAH if you are wondering it yourself, it probably means you could upvote the question to give it a bit of visibility.

Comment: Done. I know there's an `avahi-aliases` that can work on Ubuntu. I'm hoping there's a similar thing that I can do with Bonjour.

Comment: Did you figure it out? Even duplicating in /etc/hosts doesn't work.